# Insert a html code containing php tags in a js varibale

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML logic in **main_business.php**

```
<div class="large reveal full-size" id="business-modal" data-reveal>
    <?php
        $model = new Form('my-form');
        echo $this->renderPartial('//my/business', array('model'=>$model)); 
    ?>
</div>
```

and I have another file **script.js** containging a function `open` as

```
function open() {
  var $model;
}
```

Now I want to insert the content of `main_business.php` into this `$modal` variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What have you tried so far? we're here to help, not to code for you. Also, what do you mean by "the content" - the whole file? The HTML part?

Comment: yes the whole content....and I was thinking on the line of doing something like this `$model = <?php echo  file_get_contents('path to main_business.php'); ?>`....but I want to know if this is a correct approach or not

Comment: That would be a solution. But be carefull on correct syntax. `$model = file_get_content('path to main_business.php');` - Anyway, can I ask you why you want to do this? May the problem is less to get the file content, but more your approach to a solution for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `main_business.php` contains HTML of a modal which I want to show on click of a button.
On click of button I call the  `open()` function so I want to render the html at that time only.

Answer (score 0):

```
function open() {
    var modal = $('#business-modal').html();
    console.log(modal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make new variable in javascript

```
function open() {
    var model= '<?php $model ?>';
}
```